# MahApps and Catel MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mahapps.metro, catel

Is it possible to combine the MahApps visual style, including the style of the window, but the View and ViewModel from Catel? All of they require inherit window (View)

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [MahApps shell](https://github.com/WildGums/Orchestra/tree/develop/src/Examples/Orchestra.Examples.MahApps) for [Orchestra](http://github.com/wildgums/orchestra).

Comment: Can you provide some simple example? Like "WpfApplication1" just for start.